# Swift post array with afnetworking

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, post, afnetworking

I want to post some array of numbers along with other parameters, but i get the error message

`{
    error = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)";
}`

Here is what i'm trying, in my api controller i have

```
func postRequest(url: String, params: NSDictionary, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject>

    manager.POST(url, parameters: params,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        //println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
        callback(responseObject as! NSDictionary)
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
        //println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        callback(["error" : error.localizedDescription])
    })
}
```

Then in my view controller, i post with

```
    var contacts = ["xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx"]
    var params = ["id" : 1, "contacts" :  contacts ]
    api.postRequest(Constants.ApiUrl.Friends, params: params, callback: { (response) -> () in
        //self.didReceiveResponse(response)
        println(response)
    })
```

Please how can i make this post work

Comment: The standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` doesn't handle nested arrays gracefully. Many of us would want to use JSON request mechanism when sending nested structure like this. Can you change the web service to accept JSON request?

Comment: did you figure it out?